# Node.js absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, shelljs

I'm trying to build a Electron app which quickly pull the machine info to the user. I'm trying to use the npm module 'shelljs' to be able to use shell script in a node environment. But Electron doesn't really support shelljs so I'm in a bit of a pickle. There is a workaround that includes to use the absolute path to the node binary. Not sure what they mean by that so I thought you guys could help out.

---

The workaround I got is taken from [here](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs/issues/480#issuecomment-320826630) where they say this:

> Set it like any regular variable.

```js
// This is inside your javascript file

var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.config.execPath = 'path/to/node/binary'; // Replace this with the real path

// The rest of your script...
```

---

This is my code where I get an undefined on the `execPath`:

```js
const shell = require('shelljs')
const path = require('path')
shell.confic.execPath = path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'nodejs', 'node_modules', 'npm', 'bin')
```

Am I interpreting the workaround the wrong way?

Comment: I may be wrong but is there a `.bin` folder in `node_modules` folder of your app? The binaries of items stored as deps in `package.json` usually go in there. The also appears to be a typo in `shell.confic.execPath`

Comment: You can get the path to electron with `process.execPath` so probably `shell.config.execPath = process.execPath`. You can run electron has node by setting the environment variable `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1` so in your case `process.env.ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spelling error that @Chirag Ravindra pointed out did the trick. After a bit of thinking I came to this solution:

```
shell.config.execPath = path.join('C:', 'Program Files', 'nodejs', 'node.exe')
```

//Thomas